# Add CC email adress on php andoutlook

Tags: php, email, outlook

I'm using php and outlook to send automatic emails. What I desire is to mention some emails on the CC.
After thousands of search, I did not found any answers.

Below my script :

```
com_load_typelib("outlook.application");

if (!defined("olMailItem")) {
    define("olMailItem",0);
}

$outlook_Obj = new COM("outlook.application") or die("Unable to start Outlook");

$oMsg = $outlook_Obj->CreateItem(olMailItem);

$oMsg->Recipients->Add("jajaja@google.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the documentation for PHP (it seems Microsoft didn't write it yet) but I found it for VBA [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-object-outlook).

In my opinion, the relevant part is:

> The following example creates the same **MailItem** object as the preceding example, and then changes the type of the **Recipient** object from the default ("To") to CC.
>
> ```vb
> Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
>
> Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Jon Grande") 
>
> myRecipient.Type = olCC
> ```

This sample looks like the code you wrote, so the Outlook VBA interface is surely the same interface for PHP.

Additionaly, you can read the documentation for the `Type` property ([Recipient.Type Property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.type) where you can find that there are `OlMailRecipientType` constants: **olBCC**, **olCC**, **olOriginator**, or **olTo**.

**But**, I think you can't use the string "olCC" as is, if you refer to the ([olmailrecipienttype documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/vba/api/outlook.olmailrecipienttype)), you must use an integer value that corresponds to the "olCC" value.
In our case, "olCC" is 2.

So, if you use the same code as the VBA, but in PHP and use the previous documentation, it should look like this:

```php
$myRecipient = $oMsg->Recipients->Add("jajaja@google.com");
$myRecipient->Type = 2;
```

I hope it'll help. I didn't test it.

Paul

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\2.PROD_JuridicABIAT\php\JuridicABIAT_V1.0\test.php on line 9              line 9 : $myRecipientcc.Type = 2;

Comment: sorry sorry  Paul ! It's Ok ! it's $myRecipientcc->Type = 2 ; Thanks sooo much

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer, I wrote "." instead of "->" sorry :)